# Dictionary of Objects to access by Reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a binary tree in Python, where each node has an associated tuple `(a, b)`. I want to create the node objects only once, and when I subsequently access them , I want to access the previously-created node objects (because I want to modify some variables in them).

Currently, I'm using a dictionary of node objects, and a 'factory method' to create nodes. I never call `Node(a, b)` manually; the factory method does it if required. The code is

```
existing_nodes = {}

class Node:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        # stuff
        existing_nodes.update([((a, b), self)])

def get_node(a, b):
    return existing_nodes.get((a, b), Node(a, b))
```

But when I actually try to `get_node(0, 0)` in multiple places in the rest of the code, it gives me different objects. If I modify variables in one reference, it doesn't show up in the others. Also, if I `print` them, it shows different addresses.

What is going wrong? How can I create a dictionary of *references* to the node objects?

Comment: `existing_nodes.update([((a, b), self)])` is an overly verbose way of spelling `existing_nodes[a, b] = self`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never knew that works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **first** create a `Node()` instance, and only *then* test for the `(a, b)` tuple in the dictionary. Python parses your expression:

```
existing_nodes.get((a, b), Node(a, b))
```

like this:

```
t = (a, b)
n = Node(a, b)
existing_nodes.get(t, n)
```

(but without assigning to `t` and `n`), but calling `Node(a, b)` adds `self` to that same dictionary. This way you are replacing the previous node each time you call your factory function.

Don't add nodes to the dictionary from `Node.__init__`. Use the `dict.setdefault()` instead; it'll add the default to the dictionary for you if the key isn't found:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        # stuff

def get_node(a, b):
    return existing_nodes.setdefault((a, b), Node(a, b))
```

This'll still create a new `Node()` each time, but will only return it if the tuple is missing. You can avoid this altogether by just testing for the key first:

```
def get_node(a, b):
    if (a, b) not in existing_nodes:
        existing_nodes[a, b] = Node(a, b)
    return existing_nodes[a, b]
```

You could do this from a `Node.__new__` function, and not have to use a factory function:

```
class Node(object):
    _existing_nodes = {}

    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if (a, b) not in cls._existing_nodes:
            cls._existing_nodes[a, b] = super(Node, cls).__new__(cls, a, b)
        return cls._existing_nodes[a, b]

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        # stuff
```